# Curvature of the space-time in a presence of multiple gravitation sources

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

how can we measure the curvature of the space-time in a presence of multiple gravitation sources when the photon travels through a space populated by closely packed stars?

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Since the field equations are non-linear (due to gravity being one of the sources of gravity), the gravitational field of multiple bodies isn't obtained by adding together the gravitational fields of the respective bodies. Even if those are all known, you might only get approximations for their combined gravitational field.

Answer (score 1):

In the weak field limit you can add up the potentials, but in the strong field one would have to do [numerical relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3-QkujgSuM&list=PLRxi-yB7cTGc6_RtPA8g3qm2XOGfmvkoH&t=24m36s) on a supercomputer.